# Problems with events

Tags: c#

I'm using a form with a OK and a Cancel button. When the user click on the Cancel button, the user will get a message to confirm if the form should close or not. A click on OK = close, but when click on Cancel, the form should not close, but thats what is happening right know, and I have tested to add some event code for the form, but still closing. What can I do to Get it to work properly?

```
        // Button - Cancel
    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Message box to confirm or not
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to cancel and discard all data?",
"Think twice!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) ==     
DialogResult.Yes)  
        {
            // Yes
            //this.Close(); // Closes the contact form
            m_closeForm = false;
        }
        else
        {
            m_closeForm = false;
            // No
            // Do nothing, the user can still use the form
        }
    }

    private void ContactForm_Formclosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (m_closeForm)

            e.Cancel = false; // Stänger formuläret. Inget skall hända

        else

            e.Cancel = true; // Stänger inte formuläret

    }
```

Comment: "it's not working" is *never* a good description. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit your question.

Comment: Your message box with the cancel option should be in your form closing event.

Comment: Set the DialogResult property back to None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following, by adding the messagebox with the dialog result in the form closing event. I believe this is the better approach:

```
    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to cancel and discard all data?", "Think twice!",
       MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        // Form wont close if anything else is clicked
    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // PerformAction()
        this.Close();
    }
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm, but it's not the Cancel button on the form it's about, it's about the Cancel button in the messagebox that appears when the user click on the Cancel button on the form. If the user click on the cancel button in the messagebox, I want the form to stay visible. How skould the messagebox in your code be visible?

Comment: Okay now I'm really confused. Do you want a message box to appear when the user clicks a "Cancel" button located somewhere on your form? Or do you want to handle the DialogResult of clicking on a "Cancel button located in a MessageBox" when you close the form?

Comment: I have a form with a OK and a Cancel button. When the user click OK button som action will be made and the form should close. But if the user click on the Cancel button, a messagebox shows up and ask if the user really want to close the form, and if the user click OK the form should close and if the user click Cancel, the form should stay visible. I hope this is clear? Your code is working, but I get that messagebox also when I click on the OK button in the form. When click on OK in form, no meassagebox should appear

Comment: I just got it to work now as I want it without your last edit. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that in your form's Designer.cs file you'll have the following line:

```
this.btnCancel.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
```

Remove this line and your form will no longer automatically close regardless of the result of your customer MessageBox.

Answer (score 0):

To Cancel Closing you can use the `FormClosingEventArgs` Property, ie, `e.Cancel` to `true`.

Use this code in `FormClosing` Event of the Form.

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to cancel and discard all data?",
"Think twice!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) ==     
DialogResult.Yes)
{
    e.Cancel = false;
}
else
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```